# how to find urllib2

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I am new to python (I'm using python3) and I am trying to use urllib2 to learn to make web crawler.  I can't seem to find it anywhere.  I can import urllib, but urllib2 is not in the same directory as urllib and I receive an error in terminal when I try to import urllib2.

From my understanding, urllib2 is supposed to be part of pythons standard library. Where can I find it?  Is there somewhere I can just download it separately and place it into the same directory as urllib?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3 [refactored `urllib` and `urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) into a new package called [`urllib` with submodules](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.html).

Use [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) and [`urllib.error`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.error.html#module-urllib.error) instead.

Answer (score 1):

urllib2 now is called urllib, you can see it here http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#urllib-package

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3 use `urllib` like

```
urllib.request
urllib.error
urllib.parse
urllib.robotparser
```